# unable to reach to my gke pods using internal loadbalancer in gcp through port 8080

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking, internal-load-balancer

I have created a nodeport service for my tomcat app which is working on port 8080 using a yaml file , I have also created an internal loadbalancer in GCP and using this internal LB frontend static ip:port I want reach to my gke pods , but some how I am not able to.

I am suspecting that backend of the internal loadbalancer doesn't picking port 8080 , also I guess the backend of internal LB doesn't support named port in zonal network endpoint group

here is the service file for google kubernetes engine :-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: stage-validation-service
  namespace: stage-api
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"stage-validationapi-port":"TCP"}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"8080":{"name": "validationapi-neg"}}}'
spec:
  ports:
  - name : stage-validationapi-port
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    stage-api: stage-validation-api 
  type: NodePort
```

Note :- when I hit gke podip:8080 I am able to reach to the pod but when I hit internal LB ip with 8080 I am getting this error "stream timeout"

http://10.30.0.4:8080/validation/api/v1/lbhealth  ----------------------------> 10.30.0.4:8080 is the frontend ip of internal LB
http://10.80.9.36:8080/validation/api/v1/lbhealth -----------------------------> 10.80.9.36:8080 is the pod ip of my gke cluster

I just want reach my pods using internal Loadbalancer frontend IP

i have enabled firewall rule for internal LB subnet but not able to reach to my pods

here are some screenshots of Loadbalancer and Network endpoint group

[internal LB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBjsq.png)

[internal LB backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJn2i.png)

[Network endpoint group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWRE1.png)

Comment: Where are trying to reach the Internal LB from ? Also by Internal you mean the IP generate by the Service ?